# Can I use an ANOVA to analyse the effects of 2 IVs in 1 DV measured with a Likert Scale?

Tags: anova, likert

I am looking into threatened masculinity effects on men’s views of gender inequality in work. I have two independent variables: 1 is personality traits feedback (High femininity score vs High masculinity score) and 2 is evaluation of an applicant letter for a job (Female candidate vs Male candidate). My DV (gender inequality views) was measured using a hireability scale that uses a Likert-scale type.
My supervisor has asked me to find an analysis that is 2 x 2 between subjects and that allows me to test 2 main effects of IVs in the DV and 1 interaction between the 2 IVs. I thought of ANOVA since it would allow me to get these results but I am not sure if I can use it since my DV is a Likert scale. Could I use the ANOVA? And if yes, do I use the raw data of the Likert scale (wouldn’t this not work since SPSS registers all the questions as different variables?), the average scores or the sum of the scores? Also please let me know if there is any other analysis that would be more appropriate besides ANOVA.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: An ANOVA would require numerical data and Likert data are ordinal categorical data. Is you adviser suggesting that it is OK to treat the Likert data as numerical (a common, but controversial practice)? How many subjects do you have? Can you show some summary statistics? // What do you mean by 'all the questions'? Is that for the 'masculine/feminine' test? If so, it is possible to get one meaningful composite score?